# JQuery Marquee images not loading (showing?)

Tags: jquery, marquee

I have used this marquee script before with no problems (http://www.legacyoffshore.com/) but I am having a problem getting the images to show on the page I am working on now. http://www.accusealmfg.com/2011/ The navigation for the marquee shows which leads me to think it isn't a z-index issue and the images are there and have correct paths. The only error I get is this: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'imgpreload'. I'm not sure if this is my problem, if it a preload issue wouldn't the images still load, just be delayed? And I can't find any other conflicts, granted, I am a novice, so any help at all would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'imgpreload' marquee.js:96`

Answer (score 0):

After consulting one last source he fixed the problem.

```
  .marquee_photos {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      display: none;
      }
```

Remove `display: none;` and it works perfectly.